# Facebook APP API: Is there a way to see all of the people that have shared app?

Tags: facebook

As the title indicates, I'm wondering if there's a way to see all of the people that have shared an app.  If I try in the graph explorer GET/v2.8/{apptoken}/ , the node doesn't list any additional fields that I can trigger. Is there really no options for the app node?

Thanks!

Comment: No. What would you need it for anyway?

Comment: Analytics purposes. Is there any way to retrieve any information about shares, like time shared, userId, etc? @WizKid any documentation for the appId node endpoint?

Comment: No, there is not. // What fields/edges the application object has, is in the docs: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/application/

Comment: Based on my application, I figured out a way to retrieve the information I needed. Thanks for the link though!